# Map one dataframe to another based on position falling within a range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset, mapping

I have a dataframe (600k rows)

```
index  chr     position    other_cols
1      1          100      ...
2      1          2100    
3      1          3300
4      2          4
5      2          2200
6      3          8420
```

I have another dataframe df2 (1.2 million rows):

```
index          chr       start       stop
    1          1         1           100
    2          1         2000        3000 
    3          1         4000        8000 
    4          2         1           1500
    5          3         20          40000
```

I want my final dataframe to basically map df1 to df2 by finding the positions that lie within one of the regions. :

```
index  chr     position    matched_start  matched_end  other_cols (from df1)
1      1          100          1           100            ...
2      1          2100         2000        3000  
3      2          4            1           1500
4      3          8420         20          40000
```

Here's the code I've tried running, but my laptop keeps crashing everytime I try to run on the entire dfs (only works if I use small subset). I also tried doing it in chunks, but it is also crashing my laptop.

```
# Merge the DataFrames based on the 'chromosome' column
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='chr', how='inner')


# Filter the rows where variant_position lies within the start/end ranges
filtered_df = merged_df[(merged_df['position'] >= merged_df['start']) & (merged_df['position'] <= merged_df['end'])]
```

Comment: `chr` column has duplicates right? How many unique values are there in the left and right dataframes for each `chr` column ? Maybe a prefilter before merging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming there aren't any overlapping intervals for each unique `chr` (and assuming the `df2` sorted by starting position):

```py
x = df2.groupby('chr')[['start', 'stop']].agg(list)

all_dfs = []
for ch, g in df1.groupby('chr'):
    start_arr, stop_arr = np.array(x.loc[ch, 'start']), np.array(x.loc[ch, 'stop'])
    idx = np.searchsorted(start_arr, g['position']) - 1
    g.loc[:, ['matched_start', 'matched_end']] = np.array([start_arr[idx], stop_arr[idx]]).T
    all_dfs.append(g[g['position'] <= stop_arr[idx]])

df = pd.concat(all_dfs)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   index  chr  position  other_col  matched_start  matched_end
0      1    1       100          1              1          100
1      2    1      2100          2           2000         3000
3      4    2         4          4              1         1500
5      6    3      8420          6             20        40000
```

---

Initial `df1`:

```
   index  chr  position  other_col
0      1    1       100          1
1      2    1      2100          2
2      3    1      8300          3
3      4    2         4          4
4      5    2      2200          5
5      6    3      8420          6
```

Initial `df2`:

```
   index  chr  start   stop
0      1    1      1    100
1      2    1   2000   3000
2      3    1   4000   8000
3      4    2      1   1500
4      5    3     20  40000
```

Note: I did some crude benchmarking and doing this on dataframes of 600k/1.2M length took me something under 2 minutes (5700x/Python 3.10)

Comment: Thank you! I would also like to preserve the unmatched rows from df1 in a seperate df, what is the best way to do this (perhaps a merge will cause a memory issue?).

Comment: @youtube You can use the index of final `df` to filter unmatched rows from `df1`: e.g.  `df1[~df1.index.isin(df.index)]` or similar